# How can I add a user's input to an array after each loop?

Tags: java

I have a simple for loop that asks a user to enter an integer 10 times. How can I add these inputs to an array without having to make 10 separate variables?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an Integer:");
        scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Example Inputs: 10, 1, 3, 25, 33, 26, 12, 0, 7, 18

Desired Output: myArray = [10, 1, 3, 25, 33, 26, 12, 0, 7, 18]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:
This is assuming there will always be 10 numbers that you need to input

```
 public void test5(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an Integer:");
        arr[i]=scan.nextInt();
    }
    scan.close();
    //To check array output
    for(int a:arr){
      System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

If you want to make it more dynamic(array size not known beforehand) you can try this:

```
public void test6(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter Integers(in a single line separated by space):");

    int[] intArr = null;
    if(scan.hasNext()){
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        intArr = Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    }
    scan.close();
    for(int a: intArr) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] input_nums = new int [10];

    for (int i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an Integer:");
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        input_nums[i] = a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ArrayList:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an Integer:");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    array.add(number);
}
```